# NetworkManager - OpenVPN connects, but no access to the Internet

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

This happens only with this exact OpenVPN connection, only on this machine and only with NetworkManager. Regardless whether i connect to the VPN via command-line or NetworkManager itself. If i establish the Wi-Fi or Ethernet connection in some other way (dhcpcd or netctl), OpenVPN works just fine. I went as far as reinstalling the whole OS itself, didn't help.

**client.conf**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote vpn-ip 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
key-direction 1
verb 3
redirect-gateway def1
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
(certificates)
```

**ip route**

```
default via 10.188.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 10.188.183.56 metric 303 
10.188.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.188.183.56 metric 303
```

**ip route after connecting to the vpn**

```
default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 10.188.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 10.188.183.56 metric 303 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 metric 50 
10.188.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.188.183.56 metric 303 
10.188.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.188.183.57 metric 600 
10.188.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.188.183.56 metric 600 
10.188.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600 
vpn-ip via 10.188.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600
```

I've tried all kinds of things, and I honestly don't know what to do. For now i'm using wicd as a workaround, and it's working fine. I'm on Arch Linux, in case it helps. What do you think is the problem?

**UPD:** it seems to work if i change the protocol to TCP on both the server and the client. Going to investigate further.

Comment: Look into using the `NetworkManager-openvpn` plug-in tool for connecting to OpenVPN VPNs. Also ["***Note**: You must ensure that no other service that wants to configure the network is running; in fact, multiple networking services will conflict. You can find a list of the currently running services with `systemctl --type=service` and then stop them.*"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT it happens even if i establish the connection via the command line (openvpn client.conf)

Comment: are all the routes you obtain needed ?
the first one routes everything via the VPN, that might explain your problem